# Android GPS tracker какие средства использовать?

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

Одна из функций приложения должна вести мониторинг местоположения пользователя с отправкой координат местоположения на сервер. В 2018 году какими средствами актуальнее реализовывать данный функционал? Стандартные средства ос android или воспользоваться Google api?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html сейчас в 99% случаев так

Comment: Стоит прочитать
[это](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) и [вот это](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/291-urok-138-opredelenie-mestopolozhenija-gps-koordinaty.html), и картина должна прояснится